# How to correctly reference HTMLElement in VueJs component

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, ref

I have simple component, that wraps text area. And I've another simple component, that renders a button. I want to set focus to text area when clicking the button.

This simplified example fails:

```js
    <template>
      <MyCommand @resize="testResize" />
    
      <TextArea ref="refElement" />
    </template>

    <script lang="ts">
    // ...

    export default defineComponent({
      name: 'SimpleComponent',
      setup(props, context) {
        const refElement = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

        const testResize = () => {
          console.log('resize test')

          if (refElement.value !== null) {
            refElement.value.focus()
          }
        }

        return {
          refElement,
          testResize,
        }
      }    
    </script>
```

TextArea is very simple component, some input normalization, oversimplified:

```js
    <template>
      <textarea v-model.trim="value" />
    </template>
```

I get "resize test" in console, so testResize method is running, but refElement is null.

Comment: might be a problem with `TextArea`, which lib are you using? see how you can pass ref to the `TextArea`

Comment: @Naren No lib, just simple component, that wraps textarea input and makes some input normalization. You're right - when I try to use simple textarea instead of component, it works.

Any hint how to ref wrapped input inside the component?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `refElement` in your return

```js
return {
  testResize, refElement
}
```

### Update

If you are dealing with a component it becomes a bit trickier. while you *can* use `refElement.value.$el`, I'd say it's not a good idea. This will only work if the component has the first child the `textarea`. This will make for a brittle implementation, where if you need to change that at some point, it will break. IMHO, you're better off passing the ref as a prop to the child component. This is also not best practice, because you're supposed to pass props down and emit events up, but that that would be quite the overhead to implement. Passing `ref` as a prop comes with it's own issues though. If you have a `ref` in the template, it gets automagicaly converted from the ref/propxy to a value. To get around that, you can pass the prop in a function `refElement: () => refElement` in the setup(can't do it template). Of course, YMMV, but this is the path I'd chose.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup(props, context) {
    const refElement = Vue.ref(null)

    const testResize = () => {
      if (refElement.value !== null) {
        refElement.value.focus()
      }
    }

    return {
      testResize,
      refElement: () => refElement
    }
  }
});


app.component("text-area", {
  template: `<textarea ref="taRef"></textarea></div></div>`,
  props: {
    textarearef: {
      type: Function
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const taRef = props.textarearef()
    return {
      taRef
    }
  }
})

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <text-area :textarearef="refElement"></text-area>
  <button @click="testResize"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I've to return refElement too.

Unfortunately it seems like it's only part of the problem - your example uses textarea input (which works perfectly), but I'm trying to ref component, that wraps textarea.

Any hint how to ref wrapped input? I've updated my question.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing component, not a HTML element, component type should be `DefineComponent` instead of `HTMLElement`.

Wrapped element could be referenced through $el property:

```js
    <template>
      <MyCommand @resize="testResize" />
    
      <TextArea ref="refElement" />
    </template>

    <script lang="ts">
    // ...

    export default defineComponent({
      name: 'SimpleComponent',
      setup(props, context) {
        const refElement = ref<DefineComponent>()

        const testResize = () => {
          console.log('resize test')

          if (refElement.value) {
            refElement.value.$el.focus()
          }
        }

        return {
          refElement,
          testResize,
        }
      }    
    </script>
```

I'm not sure if this is the "best practice", it looks to me as a hack. If anyone knows better solution, please comment.